ROS2 Controllers Activation Issues
Problem:
I have set up controllers for my robot, but the controllers remain inactive after configuration and die shortly afterwards when loaded, then exits with the "process has died" error.
Additional Information:
RQT_GRAPH:

Console Output:
colcon build&&. install/local_setup.sh && ros2 launch movement gazebo.launch.py
Starting >>> final_description
Finished <<< final_description [0.66s]          
Starting >>> movement
Finished <<< movement [0.13s]                

Summary: 2 packages finished [1.06s]

[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/boz/.ros/log/2024-05-08-12-15-35-672331-boz-OMEN-by-HP-Laptop-17-ck2xxx-10761
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
ign_args is deprecated, migrate to gz_args!
[INFO] [ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1]: process started with pid [10762]
[INFO] [parameter_bridge-2]: process started with pid [10765]
[INFO] [joint_state_publisher-3]: process started with pid [10768]
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-4]: process started with pid [10770]
[INFO] [create-5]: process started with pid [10772]
[INFO] [rviz2-6]: process started with pid [10774]
[create-5] [INFO] [1715166936.120472919] [ros_gz_sim]: Requesting list of world names.
[parameter_bridge-2] [INFO] [1715166936.136125553] [ros_gz_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/clock (ignition.msgs.Clock) -> /clock (rosgraph_msgs/msg/Clock)] (Lazy 0)
[robot_state_publisher-4] [INFO] [1715166936.148362528] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_link
[robot_state_publisher-4] [INFO] [1715166936.148430125] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment camera_link
[robot_state_publisher-4] [INFO] [1715166936.148435048] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment camera_link_optical
[robot_state_publisher-4] [INFO] [1715166936.148438236] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment runner_plate_v1_1
[robot_state_publisher-4] [INFO] [1715166936.148441189] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment slider_1_foot_v2_1
[robot_state_publisher-4] [INFO] [1715166936.148443856] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment slider_1_foot_v2__1__1
[robot_state_publisher-4] [INFO] [1715166936.148446757] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment slider_2_feet_v2_1
[robot_state_publisher-4] [INFO] [1715166936.148449289] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment slider_2_feet_v2__1__1
[robot_state_publisher-4] [INFO] [1715166936.148451803] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment world
[joint_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1715166936.387898299] [joint_state_publisher]: Waiting for robot_description to be published on the robot_description topic...
[rviz2-6] [INFO] [1715166936.441610131] [rviz2]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[rviz2-6] [INFO] [1715166936.441696805] [rviz2]: OpenGl version: 4.6 (GLSL 4.6)
[rviz2-6] [INFO] [1715166936.458163163] [rviz2]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[create-5] [INFO] [1715166936.546720894] [ros_gz_sim]: Requested creation of entity.
[create-5] [INFO] [1715166936.546762038] [ros_gz_sim]: OK creation of entity.
[INFO] [create-5]: process has finished cleanly [pid 10772]
[INFO] [ros2-7]: process started with pid [11042]
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] libEGL warning: egl: failed to create dri2 screen
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] libEGL warning: egl: failed to create dri2 screen
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1715166938.765806727] [gz_ros2_control]: [ign_ros2_control] Fixed joint [world_to_base] (Entity=32)] is skipped
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1715166938.770730115] [gz_ros2_control]: connected to service!! robot_state_publisher asking for robot_description
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1715166938.771475093] [gz_ros2_control]: Received URDF from param server
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1715166938.783212814] [gz_ros2_control]: The position_proportional_gain has been set to: 0.1
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1715166938.783272322] [gz_ros2_control]: Loading joint: Slider_2
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1715166938.783288897] [gz_ros2_control]:   State:
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1715166938.783301661] [gz_ros2_control]:    position
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1715166938.783316884] [gz_ros2_control]:    found initial value: 0.000000
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1715166938.783331933] [gz_ros2_control]:    velocity
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1715166938.783343565] [gz_ros2_control]:   Command:
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1715166938.783353640] [gz_ros2_control]:    position
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1715166938.783397241] [gz_ros2_control]: Loading joint: Slider_6
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1715166938.783413126] [gz_ros2_control]:   State:
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1715166938.783427971] [gz_ros2_control]:    position
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1715166938.783443157] [gz_ros2_control]:    found initial value: 0.000000
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1715166938.783458167] [gz_ros2_control]:    velocity
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1715166938.783467818] [gz_ros2_control]:   Command:
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1715166938.783476713] [gz_ros2_control]:    position
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1715166938.783500068] [gz_ros2_control]: Loading joint: Slider_7
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1715166938.783511113] [gz_ros2_control]:   State:
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1715166938.783520161] [gz_ros2_control]:    position
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1715166938.783529287] [gz_ros2_control]:    found initial value: 0.000000
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1715166938.783539734] [gz_ros2_control]:    velocity
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1715166938.783548882] [gz_ros2_control]:   Command:
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1715166938.783557823] [gz_ros2_control]:    position
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1715166938.783572698] [gz_ros2_control]: Loading joint: Slider_8
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1715166938.783582068] [gz_ros2_control]:   State:
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1715166938.783590948] [gz_ros2_control]:    position
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1715166938.783599466] [gz_ros2_control]:    found initial value: 0.000000
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1715166938.783609689] [gz_ros2_control]:    velocity
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1715166938.783623157] [gz_ros2_control]:   Command:
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1715166938.783636575] [gz_ros2_control]:    position
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1715166938.783656806] [gz_ros2_control]: Loading joint: Slider_9
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1715166938.783672137] [gz_ros2_control]:   State:
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1715166938.783685674] [gz_ros2_control]:    position
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1715166938.783704136] [gz_ros2_control]:    found initial value: 0.000000
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1715166938.783721188] [gz_ros2_control]:    velocity
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1715166938.783733499] [gz_ros2_control]:   Command:
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1715166938.783742156] [gz_ros2_control]:    position
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1715166938.783840846] [resource_manager]: Initialize hardware 'IgnitionSystem' 
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [WARN] [1715166938.783867568] [gz_ros2_control]: On init...
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1715166938.783951977] [resource_manager]: Successful initialization of hardware 'IgnitionSystem'
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1715166938.784016027] [resource_manager]: 'configure' hardware 'IgnitionSystem' 
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1715166938.784024313] [gz_ros2_control]: System Successfully configured!
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1715166938.784050631] [resource_manager]: Successful 'configure' of hardware 'IgnitionSystem'
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1715166938.784070314] [resource_manager]: 'activate' hardware 'IgnitionSystem' 
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1715166938.784085746] [resource_manager]: Successful 'activate' of hardware 'IgnitionSystem'
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1715166938.784100913] [gz_ros2_control]: Loading controller_manager
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1715166938.978536914] [controller_manager]: Loading controller 'joint_state_broadcaster'
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1715166938.988190000] [controller_manager]: Configuring controller 'joint_state_broadcaster'
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1715166938.988309197] [joint_state_broadcaster]: 'joints' or 'interfaces' parameter is empty. All available state interfaces will be published
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [WARN] [1715166939.937298056] [gz_ros2_control]:  Desired controller update period (0.01 s) is slower than the gazebo simulation period (0.001 s).
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] libEGL warning: egl: failed to create dri2 screen
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] libEGL warning: egl: failed to create dri2 screen
[ros2-7] Successfully loaded controller joint_state_broadcaster into state active
[INFO] [ros2-7]: process has finished cleanly [pid 11042]
[INFO] [ros2-8]: process started with pid [11481]
[INFO] [ros2-9]: process started with pid [11483]
[INFO] [ros2-10]: process started with pid [11485]
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1715166958.353953714] [controller_manager]: Loading controller 'mid_controller'
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [WARN] [1715166958.386421028] [mid_controller]: [Deprecated]: "allow_nonzero_velocity_at_trajectory_end" is set to true. The default behavior will change to false.
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1715166966.334178464] [controller_manager]: Loading controller 'bot_controller'
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [WARN] [1715166966.345563339] [bot_controller]: [Deprecated]: "allow_nonzero_velocity_at_trajectory_end" is set to true. The default behavior will change to false.
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1715166975.609455306] [controller_manager]: Loading controller 'top_controller'
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [WARN] [1715166975.618355156] [top_controller]: [Deprecated]: "allow_nonzero_velocity_at_trajectory_end" is set to true. The default behavior will change to false.
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1715166984.759579751] [controller_manager]: Configuring controller 'mid_controller'
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [WARN] [1715166984.759699460] [mid_controller]: 'joints' parameter is empty.
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1715166984.759725218] [mid_controller]: No specific joint names are used for command interfaces. Using 'joints' parameter.
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1715166984.759765948] [mid_controller]: Command interfaces are [position] and state interfaces are [position velocity].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1715166984.759793085] [mid_controller]: Using 'splines' interpolation method.
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1715166984.761534421] [mid_controller]: Controller state will be published at 50.00 Hz.
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1715166984.763484707] [mid_controller]: Action status changes will be monitored at 20.00 Hz.
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] During ros2_control interface configuration, degrees of freedom is not valid; it should be positive. Actual DOF is 0
[INFO] [ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1]: process has finished cleanly [pid 10762]
[INFO] [launch]: process[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] was required: shutting down launched system
[INFO] [ros2-10]: sending signal 'SIGINT' to process[ros2-10]
[INFO] [ros2-9]: sending signal 'SIGINT' to process[ros2-9]
[INFO] [ros2-8]: sending signal 'SIGINT' to process[ros2-8]
[INFO] [rviz2-6]: sending signal 'SIGINT' to process[rviz2-6]
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-4]: sending signal 'SIGINT' to process[robot_state_publisher-4]
[INFO] [joint_state_publisher-3]: sending signal 'SIGINT' to process[joint_state_publisher-3]
[INFO] [parameter_bridge-2]: sending signal 'SIGINT' to process[parameter_bridge-2]
[rviz2-6] [INFO] [1715166986.573446685] [rclcpp]: signal_handler(signum=2)
[robot_state_publisher-4] [INFO] [1715166986.574467701] [rclcpp]: signal_handler(signum=2)
[parameter_bridge-2] [INFO] [1715166986.576162707] [rclcpp]: signal_handler(signum=2)
[INFO] [parameter_bridge-2]: process has finished cleanly [pid 10765]
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-4]: process has finished cleanly [pid 10770]
[ERROR] [ros2-9]: process has died [pid 11483, exit code 2, cmd 'ros2 control load_controller --set-state active mid_controller'].
[ERROR] [ros2-8]: process has died [pid 11481, exit code 2, cmd 'ros2 control load_controller --set-state active top_controller'].
[INFO] [joint_state_publisher-3]: process has finished cleanly [pid 10768]
[ERROR] [ros2-10]: process has died [pid 11485, exit code 2, cmd 'ros2 control load_controller --set-state active bot_controller'].
[INFO] [rviz2-6]: process has finished cleanly [pid 10774]

The project can be found here.

Please don't add screenshots of text.
Read the console output carefully, in the very first line there is an error message indicating why it crashed.

@ChristophFroehlich Thanks. That's what I thought at first as well.  However I couldn't find anywhere to edit the degree of freedom, is it something extra to be added?

sorry I can't help you if you don't add the full console output here.

@ChristophFroehlich Hi, I've replaced the screenshots with the complete console output

You have a typo in this line: https://github.com/BobbieZain/inchworm/blob/a99dbb9e8be6a7da9f61fe761fca5e2eefee66f3/urdf2/movement/config/ros2_controllers.yaml#L33
joints instead of joint.
I suggest to always check the parameters of your nodes with rqt_reconfigure or similar tools.

Thanks for pointing this out, I overlooked the issue as the controller files were generated by the moveit setup assistant. I'll remember to change the ROS parameters if the controller only controls a single joint.
